# Add a constant to Keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How do I add a constant to a layer?
I would have thought the following would be sufficient:

```py
a = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
b = tf.constant(1)
c = tf.keras.layers.Add()([a, b])
```

but this gives an `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

---

**Edit:**
Same error occurs with functions `Subtract`, `Maximum`, `Minimum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in this way

```
a = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
b = a + tf.constant(1.)
```

Maximum

```
a = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
b = tf.maximum(a, tf.constant(1.))
```

Comment: This indeed works due to function overloading. Why, though, does my code not work? What is the `+` overloading? Also, how would `Maximum` be used?

Comment: you have to take care also of batch dimension. Add and Maximum require tensor of the same shape... with constant, this is the easier method

Answer (score 3):

If you are using keras `Input` layer and `tf.constant` as part of regular operations, then you do as mentioned by @Marco. If you want to use them as part of model building process, then you cannot use `tf.*` ops such as `tf.constant`, `tf.maximum` etc.

In the model building, you need to use layers only. Please check the available layers [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers?version=nightly). If you want to use some tensorflow ops (tf.constant, tf.maximum etc) then you need to wrap them in keras LAMBDA layer as shown below.

```
a = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
b = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x+tf.constant(1.))(a) #
c = tf.keras.layers.Add()([a, b])
```

Another important example from TensorFlow website for `Add` layer.

```
input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(16,))
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input1)
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32,))
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(input2)
# equivalent to `added = tf.keras.layers.add([x1, x2])`
added = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "part of model building"?

Comment: If you implementing an operation (Op), then you can use `tf.maximum` but if you want to find maximum of a layer (this is part of model building), then you need to import [`maximum` layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Maximum).  In model building process you need to use layers under `tf.keras.layers`. If you want to add an op as part of model building process, then use Lambda as a layer wrap.

Comment: @VishnuvardhanJanapati can you give even more explanations on using ops vs model building?

Answer (score 0):

As [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10375049/marco-cerliani) points out in the comments, `Add`, `Maximum`, &co. require tensors of the same shape.
Thus specifying the shape of the constant is a valid solution:

```py
my_shape=(1,)
a = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=my_shape)
b = tf.constant(1, shape=my_shape)
c = tf.keras.layers.Add()([a, b])
```